# Logging Thread ID instead of Thread Name using Logback

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, logback

I have a Spring boot application and I'm using logback as the framework for logging. Currently I want to display thread id instead of the thread name. I know it is possible using log4j2 if you use `%tid` .

- Can I achieve the same using logback or should I implement a Custom Thread ID extractor?
- I'm extending `PatternLayout` class and creating a map which has the thread id and it's value. How do I use this key in my `logback.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with a custom `ClassicConverter`, such as:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

public class ThreadIdConverter extends ClassicConverter {
  @Override
  public String convert(final ILoggingEvent e) {
    return String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }
}
```

Then, in your `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <conversionRule conversionWord="threadId" converterClass="ThreadIdConverter"/>
  ...
  <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%threadId %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

By document of `log4j2`, you can use `Pattern Layout` as you know already.
so just write `%t` on your configuration file in `logback.xml`
reference document : [Link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) and find `Outputs the ID of the thread that generated the logging event.`

In my case I use like this

```
<Configuration>
  ...
  <Appenders>
    ...
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    ...
  </Appenders>
...
</Configuration>
```

Comment: [%t] prints thread name not thread id with logback.